# How to add values to a php session with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have an audio player and I want to send the time when I access another link, so when it's loaded it can continue from the exact time I pass in the session
any help?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to use PHP sessions for this?

I'd use a cookie, or if older browsers are'nt an issue, local storage, or maybe a script for using cookies on older browsers and local storage on newer browsers.

There's a handy [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) for jQuery.

Local storage is pretty straight forward aswell:

```
localStorage.setItem('timeIleft', time_variable);
```

and to retrieve:

```
var user_left = localStorage.getItem('timeIleft');
```

Comment: Good idea, I not enough use cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an [AJAX requets](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do that.

The URL will be a php page and will retrieve your data using $_POST['param-name'].

Or, check this way to call php page http://www.xajaxproject.org/